# Sendlog not logging certain records

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, exclusion-script, studio

I am using sendlog to exclude.  I have a field called campaigncode in my entry source.

-The Sendlog has a field called campaigncode
-The entry source has some records that have a blank under campaign code

I am noticing that upon send - sendlog wont log records that have NO CAMPAIGN CODE - is that the reason? In oreder for a record to appear in the sendlog - do they have to have populated values for each field in the Sendlog DE?

is there anyway to rectify this without putting in a fake value for all email sends?

I want to have records that have no campaign code to appear inside the Send log DE

[image]

```
%%[

  var @ex_exclude
  var @ex_rows
  var @ex_rowcount

  set @ex_exclude = 0

  /* retrieve the most recent send for this subscriber */
  set @ex_rows = LookupOrderedRows("tm_Sendlog", 1, "eventdate desc", "emailaddr", AttributeValue("emailaddr"))
  
  set @ex_rowcount = rowcount(@ex_rows)
  
set @campaigncode = AttributeValue('campaigncode')

  if @ex_rowcount > 0 AND @campaigncode != 'hfnse' then

     var @ex_row
     var @ex_eventDate
     var @ex_yesterday
     
     set @ex_row = row(@ex_rows, 1)

     set @ex_eventDate = field(@ex_row,"eventDate")
     set @ex_yesterday = dateadd(now(),'-1','D')

     if @ex_eventDate > @ex_yesterday then 
       set @ex_exclude = 1
     endif

  endif

]%%
%%=v(@ex_exclude)=%%
<br>
campaigncode is: %%=v(@campaigncode)=%%
```

Comment: It depends on how you set up the SendLog - Is the campaigncode a required field in the SendLog DE?

Comment: It is not - it is nullable and that is why I am puzzled

Comment: I have added my code above on targeting the SEND DE - you can see my logic in the original comment if that helps - when the email is sent it is NOT logging people who have EMPTY/Null values for campaign code

Answer (score 1):

The (very helpful indeed)  documentation states:

```
The send log can fail if you add custom fields for the data extension send logs.
```

Without stating any reason.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_send_logging_best_practices.htm&type=5

What I do know is that the variables you use in SendLog need to be in the DE for every send.

Do they need to be populated - not sure, but what you are doing is actually more specific:

In the code you share, AttributeValue() sets your variable from empty string to `null`. (https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/)
This could push the sendlog from logging empty string (which might still work) to assuming that the variable is non-existent (which SendLog does not like).

try this:

a) remove the AttributeValue() function and just work with the data extension field

b) if a) does not work, change your code:

```
set @campaigncode = AttributeValue('campaigncode')
IF empty(@campaignCode) THEN 
  SET @campaignCode = ''
ENDIF
```

try it with resetting to empty string instead of null. If that also fails,

c) Set it to a dummy, start with `" "` (one empty space) or something that you can reliably exclude as a "defaultvalue".

And please let us if it worked, and which of the three options :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!  I can try this when I get home - can you elaborate on bullet a? By work with the data extension field do you mean instead of AttributeValue(campaigncode)  I do something like set @campaigncode = %%campaigncode%%?  THanks!

Comment: Yes, that, but you need to omit the `%%` when in an AMPScript definition block. Just `SET @campaignCode = campaignCode` will pull the value for you.